# Is it possible to restrict access to some folders in a single aws s3 bucket to different users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, backend, amazon-iam

I am building an application to allow users to organize their files/folders.

I am using an AWS S3 bucket under the hood to store the files.

I read that it wasn't a good practice to have a bucket per user architecture since it is not designed for that purpose but I am not comfortable having to check myself that no one access to others files.

Is there a way to restrict some folders (and their subcontent) to some users inside a bucket ?

Comment: I think this is what are you looking for: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-s3-user-specific-folder/

Comment: thanks ! I am fairly a newbie with AWS, but is it common practice to dynamically add a new policy for each new user in order to restrict their access to their own folders ?

Comment: In this case, 1 policy is enough. Using variables in the policy (e.g. you can refer to the username as ${aws:username}) gives you flexibility. If there is not a supported variable that matches your case, then you could take an tag based approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use object tagging and attribute based access control to deny/allow access to objects. A lot of documentation can be found by googling.

ABAC in a nutshell:

- S3 objects are assigned a tag contaiming a some value (user id, project id, department id)
- Users are assigned a tag containing a some value (user id, project id, department id)
- Access is granted if the values match.

Comment: Why on earth would anyone maintain tags, when you can simply create a policy which restricts based on prefix: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-s3-user-specific-folder/

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi In organizations where ABAC is used as a primary access control method, this should be of course the way to do it. With regard to the OP's user case, my answer was to provide an alternative to prefix based conditional access control. Also AWS has extensively published material related to this approach. See for example, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-scale-authorization-needs-using-attribute-based-access-control-with-s3/

Comment: thanks for your answer and comment. Looking at the example for prefix-based policies it looks like it is for users inside the company (employees etc...). I know it might just be for the example but I can't help wondering: what is the common good practice for end-users (customers) ? Restrict policies based on tags or on prefix ?

Comment: @GaneD.Geoffrey I think it really depends on your overall application architecture. 

For example, if you were using Amazon Cognito for
end-user/customer authentication, you could assign end users AWS IAM role and use that role to control access not only to S3 resources but also  other AWS services.
In this scenario tag-based access control would be a good decision, but of course it is possible to use normal RBAC (role based access control) too. 

On the other hand, if you use your own/3rd party methods for app IAM, more common prefix based access control could be the first choice.